# Override Vim's filetype setting for octave

Tags: vim

GNU Octave and Matlab share the `.m` suffix, but Octave's syntax is a little different, like allowing `#` as a comment.

I created a `scripts.vim`, but that does not get called since the filetype is already set to Matlab.

That is the snippet that I use, it works, but it never gets executed in `~/.vim/scripts.vim` or if I put it into `~/.vim/ftdetect/octave.vim`

```
if getline(1) =~ '^#!/.*octave'                                        
    set filetype=octave
endif
```

Where can I set this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with the `filetype.vim` now:

```
" ~/.vim/filetype.vim

if exists("did_load_filetypes")
    finish
endif

function! DetectOctave()
    echom getline(1)
    if getline(1) =~ '^#!/.*octave.*'                                        
        set filetype=octave
    endif
endfunction

augroup filetypedetect
    au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.m  call DetectOctave()
augroup END
```

Comment: Please mark this answer correct so people will know the problem has been solved.